# htaccess file contains conflicting rules - multiple page types and similar rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 types of pages that follow very similar rules.  I am trying to rewrite the rules for each page type and I am running into some issues.

```
RewriteRule (mission|story|advertise)\.html $1.php [L]

##Symptom Pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/health-food.html (condition duplicated for all category page urls)
RewriteRule ^health-conditions/([^.]+)\.html?$  php/symptom.php?symptoms_url=$1 [L]
#http://www.example.com/conditions/autism.html

##Email Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^.]+)/([^.]+)\.html?$  php/email.php?slug=$1&region_slug=$2&vendor_Slug=$3&email=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

##Vendor Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html?$  php/vendor.php?slug=$1&region_slug=$2&vendor_Slug=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

##Listing Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^.]+)\.html?$  php/listing.php?slug=$1&region_slug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
#http://www.example.com/allergy-specialists-new-york.html


##Category Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html?$  php/category2.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
#http://www.example.com/allergy-specialists.html
```

The 2-word states (listing pages) cause the wrong file to load. http://www.example.com/allergy-specialists-new-york.html does not work but http://www.example.com/allergy-specialists-ohio.html does work.

I have tried switching the order and that only causes othe pages to pull the wrong file.  Please help.

Thank you

Comment: I think I have figured out what the issue is here, I just don't know how to fix it.  It's a problem with the "Listing Page" rule which has ([^/]+)-([^.]+) as part of the rule.  So it's not clear how long the first string is and the second string so it's not finding the correct parts from the url to send to the page to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this was to add the word "in" into the Listing Page urls (ie: example.com/allergy-specialists-in-new-york.html).  This corrected any conflicting htaccess rules.